# Anything new in the "low quality" algorithm?

Tags: discussion

I just got presented with a **2 years old** answer, *"flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."* (Answered and edited by another user on  Apr 14, 2011. No activity since.)

https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/153034

That looks a little strange, doesn't it?

Comment: You will think I'm joking, but seems that the system thinks we are too bored so it makes us look to old answers/questions to check for correctness... or hidden gems

Comment: It's just doing some fall cleaning ;)